# CloudFormation template stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS when creating ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm creating a ECS service in CloudFormation.

I receive no error, it just will sit at the CREATE_IN_PROGRESS on the `logical ID = Service` phase..

Here's my CF template (ECS cluster & some other stuff above but cut out due to relevance).

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      Family: flink
      Memory: 2048
      Cpu: 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE 
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: flink-jobmanager
          Image: ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/teststack-flink:latest
          Essential: true
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8081
              HostPort: 8081
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: ecs/flink-stream
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
          Command:
            - jobmanager
        - Name: flink-taskmanager
          Image: ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/teststack-flink:latest
          Essential: true
          Command:
            - taskmanager
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      Volumes: []
      TaskRoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      Tags:
        -
          Key: EnvironmentStage
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentStage

  Service:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Join ['', [!Ref EnvironmentStage, '-', !Ref 'AWS::StackName']]
      Cluster: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:ecs:', !Ref 'AWS::Region', ':', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':cluster/', !Ref ECSCluster]]
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 75
      TaskDefinition: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:ecs:', !Ref 'AWS::Region', ':', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':task-definition/', !Ref TaskDefinition]]
      # TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      EnableECSManagedTags: true
      PropagateTags: TASK_DEFINITION
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref FlinkSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - subnet-466da11c
            - subnet-6fe65509
      Tags:
        -
          Key: EnvironmentStage
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentStage
```

The containers both deploy to the cluster when I set it up manually

Comment: Does it successfully create the task definition?

Comment: Can you acheck ECS->Service->Events? What does it say?

Comment: @DennisTraub yes, TaskDefinition finished already

Comment: @Marcin Under `events` all it says is status = `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` and status reason = `Resource creation Initiated` for logical ID = `service`

Comment: Can you check ECS->Service->Tasks->Stopped? If you've any tasks in STOPPED state that means it's unable to spin up a container. You would be able to find the exact reason why the tasks were STOPPED by clicking on any task id.

Comment: Does the image on ECR actually exist? It can be a simple Hello World, but you may need to have _something_ for the task definition to do so it cant work.

Comment: @kk. When I navigate there & click `logs` there is nothing... but there are three stopped tasks. I just see no details about why

Comment: @OscarDeLeón This ECR image does exist, I copied the exact repo & image name from the resources in the console.

Comment: @kk. actually.. I found this: ```Status reason CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist.```

Comment: @kk. after adding the creation of a log group (which I forgot to do) it completed successfully. Thank you for pointing that spot out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking `clusters -> CLUSTER_NAME -> tasks -> stopped` I saw the following:

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: 
failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: 
ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist.
```

The issue was simply that I forgot to add the creating of a `log group` to to my CF template.. So I added this:

```
  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub ${EnvironmentStage}-service-flink
```

Then modified the `LogConfiguration` in `TaskDefinition` to this:

```
LogConfiguration:
  LogDriver: awslogs
  Options:
    awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
    awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
    awslogs-stream-prefix: flink
```

Now the CF template works like a charm :)